# How to match a word that contains symbols?

Tags: regex

I have this string `This is a test -[[message]]-` and I want to match `-[[message]]-`

This is my trying `\w+$`

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\S`, a negative character class matching any character that is not a whitespace character (such as space, tab, new line, etc.):

```
\S+
```